# How to switch pyqt5 dialogs multiple times back and forth?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to switch between dialogs multiple times but the code i have right now only does the switching 2 times then it just stops.

1. first Dialog to second Dialog (no issue)
2. second Dialog to Dialog first (no issue)
3. First Dialog to Second Dialog (so when i try to go to second dialog again the code stops running)

I have tried setting the visibility True and False instead instead of closing the the dialog and also used Dialog.exec_() instead of Dialog.exec()

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(633, 242)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 401, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.page_2)

    def page_2(self):
        start_D2()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog_1"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Go to Second Page"))


class Ui_Dialog_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(633, 242)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 401, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.page_1)

    def page_1(self):
        start_D1()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog_2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Go to First Page"))


def start_D2():
    try:

        Dialog.close()
        ui = Ui_Dialog_2()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog_2)
        Dialog_2.exec()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def start_D1():
    try:

        Dialog_2.close()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.exec()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    Dialog_2 = QtWidgets.QDialog()

    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What i need is to switch dialogs every time i click the button not just once or twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- Qt for efficiency does not throw exceptions so it is not necessary to use try-except.
- PyQt I recommend not to modify the code generated by QtDesigner because it is not a widget in the first place, it is just a class that is used to fill a widget. Instead, you must create another class that inherits the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it. For more information read the [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code).

The solution is that when you press the button, close the same dialog and open the other window.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(633, 242)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 401, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog_1"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Go to Second Page"))


class Ui_Dialog_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(633, 242)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 401, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog_2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Go to First Page"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # close the window
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)


class Dialog2(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog_2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # close the window
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w1 = Dialog()
    w2 = Dialog2()
    # open another dialog
    w1.pushButton.clicked.connect(w2.show)
    w2.pushButton.clicked.connect(w1.show)
    w1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```